# What numpy version is compatible with Python 3.7?

Tags: python, numpy, version, compatibility

The Goddard Mission Analysis Tool, GMAT 2020a python version is constrained to Python 3.7 due to a binary dependency in GMAT libPythonInterface.dll

When running a python userfunction I get the notorious numpy exception:

> No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'

Additional text in the error message attempts to be helpful and directs the user to (https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html) but the suggestions there are generic, erroneous, and incomplete.

Comment: try python3.7 -m pip install numpy - see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60837548/cannot-import-numpy-in-python-3-7-or-python-3-8-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: Tried that, I got numpy v1.21.  According to the NEP below, there is a change in numpy at 1.19 that is not backwards compatible.

Comment: According to the metadata shown on PyPI, the last released version of NumPy to support Python 3.7 is 1.21 (e.g. https://pypi.org/project/numpy/1.21.6/).

Comment: Yes but nonetheless you get the "No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath' error" with numpy1.21 and Python3.7.

Answer (score 5):

After much research, I uncovered a description of numpy-python version dependencies at (https://numpy.org/neps/nep-0029-deprecation_policy.html) and I want to document it here, for myself as well as other users.

In addition, using conda and it's wonderful dependency checker, I have uncovered the following versions of common applications (that I use with GMAT) as follows:

-numpy 1.16

-matplotlib 3.4

-scipy 1.5.3

-xlwings-0.26.3

-xlsxwriter-3.0.2

-PyQt5 5.12

Comment: According to the document `1.18` seems to be the last version supporting `py3.7`.

Comment: Yes that's the way I read it, yet both PIP and Conda will install 1.21 with 3.7. At any rate with GMAT 2022a coming soon, we should be able to update out of this mess.  I have had limited success with Numpy 1.18, but there is one library in SciPy that causes numpy to throw the invalid np array exception, the elliptical integrals.  If you use these as I do then Numpy 1.16 is the one to use.